# Better way to implement position-based scrolling effect

Tags: android

I have written a custom `View`, let's call it `CustomListView` that extends `LinearLayout`. The `CustomListView` uses an `Adapter` to create its children. I have also implemented a behavior where a child is rendered differently when it's positioned in a specific way--for example, when you scroll through the list, the background of the child that's currently visible at the top of the list becomes transparent. So for example:

Starting:

```
+-----------------------------+
| child 1 (transparent bg)    |
+-----------------------------+
| child 2 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 3 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 4 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 5 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 6 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
```

After scrolling down to where child 3 is at the top of the list:

```
+-----------------------------+
| child 3 (transparent bg)    |
+-----------------------------+
| child 4 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 5 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 6 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 7 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
| child 8 (visible)           |
+-----------------------------+
```

The problem is that I am not very happy with the way I have achieved this. At the moment, the way I do this by creating a custom `View`, `CustomListViewChild`, that inherits from `RelativeLayout` and which I use as the root view for each child. This is the relevant part of the implementation of the `CustomListViewChild`:

```
public final class CustomListViewChild extends RelativeLayout {

    private OnScrolledToListener onScrolledToListener;
    private OnScrolledFromListener onScrolledFromListener;

    /**
     * Called when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled to (i.e. it is now at the top of the
     * {@link CustomListView})
     */
    public void scrollTo() {
        if (onScrolledToListener != null) {
            onScrolledToListener.onScrolledTo();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled from (i.e. it is no longer at the
     * top of the {@link CustomListView})
     */
    public void scrollFrom() {
        if (onScrolledFromListener != null) {
            onScrolledFromListener.onScrolledFrom();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param onScrolledToCallback a listener to be called when this {@link CustomListViewChild} is
     *            scrolled to (i.e. the scroll of the {@link CustomListView} has come to an end with this
     *            {@link CustomListViewChild} at the top).
     */
    public void setOnScrolledToListener(OnScrolledToListener onScrolledToCallback) {
        this.onScrolledToListener = onScrolledToCallback;
    }

    /**
     * @param onScrolledFromCallback a listener to be called when this view is scrolled away from
     *            (i.e. this was previously the top {@link CustomListViewChild} in the {@link CustomListView}
     *            but now the user has scrolled away from it.)
     */
    public void setOnScrolledFromListener(OnScrolledFromListener onScrolledFromCallback) {
        this.onScrolledFromListener = onScrolledFromCallback;
    }

    /**
     * An interface used to listen for when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled to.
     */
    public interface OnScrolledToListener {
        /**
         * Method called when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled to.
         */
        void onScrolledTo();
    }

    /**
     * An interface used to listen for when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled from.
     */
    public interface OnScrolledFromListener {
        /**
         * Method called when this {@link CustomListViewChild} has been scrolled from.
         */
        void onScrolledFrom();
    }
}
```

Then, in my `Adapter`:

```
if (convertView instanceof CustomListViewChild) {
    ((CustomListViewChild) convertView).setOnScrolledFromListener(new OnScrolledFromListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolledFrom() {
            viewHolder.screenshot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    ((CustomListViewChild) convertView).setOnScrolledToListener(new OnScrolledToListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolledTo() {
            viewHolder.screenshot.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

This feels hacky and not extensible though. If I should ever decide to have a Child that's another kind of layout (say, `LinearLayout`) I would have to provide another custom class, or ideally figure out a way to do this with an interface... let's just say it's not ideal.

Another approach I literally just thought of is having my `CustomListViewAdapter` provide callbacks to the `CustomListView` that will be called when a `View` is scrolled to or away from. This actually seems quite a bit better already, but I'm not sure if it breaks the `Adapter`s abstraction. I am curious if there are any other approaches I haven't considered.